# jQuery Selector : Replacing text matched by a regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to find a SPAN with a CSV (actually semi-colon delimited) text node and replace it with a URL constructed using info from the CSV.  NOTE: The CSV actually contains 6 values -- only 3 shown here for brevity.

I want to replace a bunch of lines like this :

```
<span>1;2;Some text</span>
```

with lines like this:

```
<span><a href="blah...&a=1&b=4&c=2 ..etc.">Some text</a>
```

I'm using jQuery's .filter with a function that checks the text node using a regex ([as per this StackExchange post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/)).

```
jQuery('blah..blah span').filter( function(){
  var regex_Rslt = 
   (this.textContent || this.innerText).match( /(\d+);(\d+);(.+)/ ); 
  if (regex_Rslt) {
    // Replace the contents of "this" here?
    this.textContent =  ...format URL from regex_Rslt[0..etc] ;
    return true ;
  } else {
    return false ;
  }
}) ;
```

**The question is**: Should I modify the contents of the text node *inside* the .filter function?  My first reaction is "**NO!**" -- the function's purpose is to *find* elements, not *modify* them.  On the other hand, inside the .filter function I have the CSV all parsed up and ready to be used.

Alternative?  In the .filter function use the parsed CSV to create the URL and save it in an Object, then use .each to iterate the matching elements replace them with the appropriate URL created in the filter function.

```
var hrefs = {} ;
jQuery('blah..blah span').filter( function(idx){
  var regex_Rslt = 
   (this.textContent || this.innerText).match( /(\d+);(\d+);(.+)/ ); 
  if (regex_Rslt) {
    // Don't do replacement here - do it after the selection.
    // Use 'this' or 'idx' as key???
    hrefs[this] = ...format URL from regex_Rslt[0..etc] ;
    return true ;
  } else {
    return false ;
  }
}).each( function(idx) {
  // use 'this' or 'idx' as the Object key??
  this.textContent = hrefs[this] ;
}) ;
```

Comment: my suggestion `hrefs = [];` and `hrefs.push(<format url>);`, `hrefs[idx]`

Comment: I don't see the connection between `1;2;Some text` and `blah...&a=1&b=4&c=2 ..etc.`. Furthermore, the second string is so weird that I've quite simply stopped reading...